# ask runtime permissions for onMapsReady android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

i have a phone with android 6.0, and the method onMapReady is not execute, because i think need runtime permissions, and i dont know how to do that, this is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap map;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    String email;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        FirebaseUser user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        //obtener datos para la barra
        if(user != null) {

            String nombre=user.getDisplayName();
            email=user.getEmail();
            Uri foto=user.getPhotoUrl();

            NavigationView navigationsView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            View hView =  navigationsView.getHeaderView(0);
            TextView nav_user = (TextView)hView.findViewById(R.id.txtMail);
            TextView name=(TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
            ImageView img_user = (ImageView)hView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

            name.setText(nombre);
            nav_user.setText(email);
            Picasso.with(this).load(foto).into(img_user);
        }
        else {
            SharedPreferences loginbdd=getSharedPreferences("login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            email=loginbdd.getString("nombre","");
            String nombre=loginbdd.getString("mail","");

            NavigationView navigationsView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            View hView =  navigationsView.getHeaderView(0);
            TextView nav_user = (TextView)hView.findViewById(R.id.txtMail);
            TextView name=(TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
            ImageView img_user = (ImageView)hView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

            nav_user.setText(email);
            name.setText(nombre);
        }

    }

    private void goLogin() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.cerrar).setTitle("Cerrar Aplicación").setMessage("Deseas cerrar CicloMapp?")
                    .setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }

                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.endSession) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.cerrar)
                    .setTitle("Cerrar sessión")
                    .setMessage("Deseas cerrar sesión?")
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                            if(user!= null){
                                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                                goLogin();
                            }else{
                                SharedPreferences loginbdd=getSharedPreferences("login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=loginbdd.edit();
                                editor.remove("inicio");
                                editor.commit();
                                goLogin();
                            }
                        }

                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.AgregarRuta) {

        } else if (id == R.id.ValorarRuta) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Valoraraciones.class);
            i.putExtra("correo", email);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (id == R.id.ReportarRuta) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Reportar.class);
            i.putExtra("correos", email);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (id == R.id.Eventos) {

        } else if (id == R.id.Refresco) {

        } else if (id == R.id.Leyes) {

        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map=googleMap;
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        map.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(-33.447487,-70.673676));
        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11);
        map.moveCamera(center);
        map.animateCamera(zoom);
        Polyline po = new Polyline();
        po.AddPolyline(map);

        int height = 50;
        int width = 50;
        BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mruta);
        Bitmap b = bitmapdraw.getBitmap();

        Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
        final Marcadores ma=new Marcadores();
        ma.MarcadoreBdd(map,smallMarker);

    }

}
```

maybe the onmylocation needs permissions ithink

ps: works perfect with android 4.4, the problem is with android 6.0 or higher

Comment: *maybe the onmylocation needs permissions ithink* luckily that is easy to pinpoint, because it tells you.

Comment: can you help me? i dont know how to implements runtime permissions

Comment: Maybe google knows

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with the runtime permissions when upgrading my app to a new Android version.

But I found this post very helpful:

https://inducesmile.com/android/android-6-marshmallow-runtime-permissions-request-example/
(The code below comes from this).

Basically, you need to check if you have the permissions in your App when you need them (perhaps during startup in your case) with code such as this;

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(WebActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(WebActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, MY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Then, you need to handle a response in an onRequestPermissionsResult method

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //You have permission, so continue
        }else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(WebActivity.this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {
                //Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously*
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(WebActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, MY_REQUEST_CODE);
            }else{
                //Never ask again and handle your app without permission.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget that you still need the permissions to be specified in your MANIFEST file.

Comment: the first two lines of your code, should be in onstart method? i dont understand

Comment: You need to call this at the place where your App needs these permissions.  This could be anywhere in your APP.  But in your case, you probably need this in the onCreate method.  Look at the example in the link.